# Arcgis updating current location when user travel ios

Tags: ios, gps, arcgis

Hi i am using the below code to display current location on the map. I notice that the current location does not seem to be updating when i travel around. I would like the location indicator to update the pointer according to the place i travel. How would i go about doing this? Currently only able to display the current location on the map and that is it.

```
[self.mapView.locationDisplay startDataSource];
self.mapView.locationDisplay.autoPanMode = AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanModeCompassNavigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might Listen for location updates:

```
- (void)registerAsObserver {
  [ self.mapView.locationDisplay addObserver:self
                      forKeyPath:@"location"
                         options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
                         context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if ([keyPath isEqual:@"location"]) {
   NSLog(@"Location updated to %@", [self.mapView.locationDisplay mapLocation]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying wanderExtentFactor - add one more line of code, wanderExtentFactor can take values from 0 to 1 just play around to see which settings suit you best

```
[self.mapView.locationDisplay startDataSource];
self.mapView.locationDisplay.autoPanMode = AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanModeCompassNavigation;
self.mapView.locationDisplay.wanderExtentFactor = 0.5;
```